# External script not executed inside div block which is being dynamically refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am running a wordpress where content is being added dynamically using a RSS plugin and I have made some modifications where it adds div block inside the loaded content in which there is a script tag with external javascript, this is for advertisements. So basically it looks something like this -

```
<ul loaded dynamically with RSS plugin>
  <li item from RSS plugin>
  </li>
    <div placeholder for advertisement>
      <script with external src which shows actual advert></script
    </div>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This RSS plugin also adds pagination.

When page is first accessed, it loads just fine, script in div block is executed and shows as expected, but when selecting next page for this RSS plugin, it dynamically loads all the next items in next page (actual page is not reloaded/refreshed, just the plugin content) but the script from div is not being executed/shown, it is just blank so I guess it somehow does not execute, also when selecting the previous page again where it was showing first time, it just does not run again, looks like this RSS plugin kills the script from div block.
Is there a way to somehow reload/re-execute this script whenever I select next page etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some extra details about the script and the plugin would better clarify the issue here...

Comment: The plugin is called WP RSS Aggregator and script is just a simple <script type="text/javascript" src="ADnetworkURL"></script>, anything could be in the script part, it just wont work